# Compare `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` to Oracle `DATE`?

Tags: scala, jodatime, anorm

Using anorm, given a `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime`, how I compare that to an Oracle `DATE` column?

I tried to convert the `LocalDateTime` to a `LocalDate` via `LocalDateTime#toLocalDate`, however I encountered:

```
TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 2016-10-30 00:00:00.0: class 
     java.sql.Timestamp to String for column 
          ColumnName(.COLUMN_NAME,Some(COLUMN_NAME))))
```

Comment: Ultimately, I used a `org.joda.time.LocalDate`, as well as used `import anorm.JodaParameterMetaData._` per https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/play-framework/I6TnTzO5MUw/_LlAL_RotGgJ.